# SVN Server with Apache can let me access my files anywhere! Firefox seems otherwise

Tags: svn, firefox, visualsvn

I just installed Visual SVN Server and I just found that I can access my files using plain browsers like IE or Chrome.

I can even stream an mp3 file from my home to my work that way... or access any files at home if i forward the port to the Visual SVN server...

although i noted that IE 8 will show a red background for the current URL... so the link is not easily readable...   also Firefox simply refused to open the page, reporting that the certificate is self-signed...  any one know to make Firefox 3 be able to open it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get the screen that says "Secure Connection Failed", follow these steps:

1. There should be a link that says "Or you can add an exception...". Click on that link.
2. Then click the button that says "Add Exception..."
3. Click the "Get Certificate" button
4. Make sure the "Permanently store this exception" checkbox is checked
5. Click the "Confirm Security Exception" button.

At this piont you should be prompted for your credentials, and everything should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom the page talking about the certificate, there should be a link that says "Add an exception." Follow that link, click on "get / view certificate" (sorry, going from memory), then "add exception."

Essentially, it's just complaining about the SSL certificate's origin. You can get rid of the red background in IE8 by adding the certificate there as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows Authentication to your repositories, you must use https and not http to access those with an svn client. For security reasons, neon (the default DAV library subversion clients use) has SSPI (the windows authentication) disabled for non-encrypted connections.

Comment: Visual SVN uses https, the problem his is having is the secured server certificate isn't signed